# Kernel death when generating a complicated schedule

Tags: python, memory-leaks, out-of-memory

Trying to generate a complicated schedule where 3 people present each week, 1 brings lunch, and 1 brings coffee while trying to space all of these out over time as much as possible. A script is preferred over just looping the people because availabilities and potential presenters change all the time and this has proven tricky to do manually with this many people.

I've come up with a script that should be able to do this (below), but the kernel keeps crashing even after adding in batch processing. It's being run on a remote slurm server with 60G memory and 15 CPUs which should be plenty (I use this for CNNs etc).

Any help you can provide to identify the memory leakage/ways to fix it is much appreciated.

Here is the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import csv
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import itertools

def generate_weekly_schedule(people_availability, start_date, end_date):
    # Create a list of all available dates within the specified range
    available_dates = [start_date + timedelta(days=i) for i in range((end_date - start_date).days + 1)]
    # Initialize the schedule
    schedule = []
    for date in available_dates:
        # Filter out people who are not available on this date
        available_people = [person for person, unavailable_dates in people_availability.items() if date not in unavailable_dates]
        if not available_people:
            continue  # Skip the date if no one is available

        # Try to select the presenter for the main presentation
        main_presentation = None
        for person in available_people:
            if all(date + timedelta(days=i) not in people_availability[person] for i in range(7)):
                main_presentation = person
                break
        if main_presentation is None:
            continue  # Skip the date if we couldn't find a main presenter

        # Shuffle the list of available people to randomize the selection of highlights, lunch, and coffee
        random_order = list(itertools.permutations(available_people))
        for order in random_order:
            if main_presentation not in order:
                highlights = order[:2]  # Assign the first two people in the shuffled list to highlights
                lunch_and_coffee_candidates = order[2:]
                break

        # Ensure that lunch and coffee providers are not presenting
        lunch_provider = None
        coffee_provider = None

        for person in lunch_and_coffee_candidates:
            if date + timedelta(days=7) not in people_availability[person] and lunch_provider is None:
                lunch_provider = person
            elif date + timedelta(days=7) not in people_availability[person] and coffee_provider is None:
                coffee_provider = person

        # Append the schedule for this date
        schedule.append([date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"), main_presentation, highlights[0], highlights[1], lunch_provider, coffee_provider])

    return schedule

def write_schedule_to_csv(schedule, csv_filename):
    with open(csv_filename, mode='w', newline='') as file:
        writer = csv.writer(file)
        writer.writerow(["Date", "Main Presentation", "Highlight 1", "Highlight 2", "Lunch Provider", "Coffee Provider"])
        writer.writerows(schedule)

def batch_process_and_merge(people_availability, start_date, end_date, batch_size):
    batched_schedule = []
    current_date = start_date
    while current_date <= end_date:
        batch_end_date = min(current_date + timedelta(days=batch_size - 1), end_date)
        batch_schedule = generate_weekly_schedule(people_availability, current_date, batch_end_date)
        batched_schedule.extend(batch_schedule)
        current_date = batch_end_date + timedelta(days=1)
    return batched_schedule

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Example input dictionary of people and their unavailable dates
    people_availability = {
        "Person 1": [(datetime(2023, 9, 8), datetime(2023, 9, 20))],
        "Person 2": [(datetime(2023, 9, 8), datetime(2023, 10, 13))],
        "Person 3": [],
        "Person 4": [],
        "Person 5":[(datetime(2023, 10, 1), datetime(2023, 12, 15))],
        "Person 6": [],
        "Person 7": [],
        "Person 8": [datetime(2023, 11, 10), datetime(2023, 11, 17)],
        "Person 9": [],
        "Person 10":[],
        "Person 11": [],
        "Person 12": [(datetime(2023, 10, 27), datetime(2023, 12, 15))],
        "Person 13": [datetime(2023, 9, 15)],
        "Person 14": [(datetime(2023, 9, 8), datetime(2023, 12, 15))],
        "Person 15": [(datetime(2023, 9, 8), datetime(2023, 12, 15))],
        "Person 16": [(datetime(2023, 9, 8), datetime(2023, 12, 15))],
        "Person 17": [],
        "Person 18": [],
        "Person 19": [datetime(2023, 9, 22), datetime(2023, 11, 3)],
        "Person 20": [],
        "Person 21": [],
        "Person 22": [],
        "Person 23": [datetime(2023, 9, 8), datetime(2023, 9, 13)],
        "Person 24": [datetime(2023, 9, 8), datetime(2023, 9, 30)],               
    }

    start_date = datetime(2023, 9, 8)
    end_date = datetime(2023, 12, 15)
    batch_size = 7 

    batched_schedule = batch_process_and_merge(people_availability, start_date, end_date, batch_size)
    write_schedule_to_csv(batched_schedule, "weekly_schedule.csv")
```

I tried adding batch processing and increasing the number of CPUs, but there must be some data leakage I'm not seeing as I assume this shouldn't require so many computing resources.

Answer (score 2):

So I tested your code using a debugger to step through and I found that the line that consumes all of your memory is this: `random_order = list(itertools.permutations(available_people))`. This is a very deceptive line because all you are trying to do is fill a list with all possible permutations. However, since your list has 22 items in it, your list will need 22^22 items in it, which I think is about 300 octillion items. With an iterator like this, you can't afford to unload it into a list, you will have to go through it item by item.

I'm not sure how you will want to implement your logic here, but using `random_order = itertools.permutations(available_people)` to keep it as an iterator should prevent it from trying to acquire more memory than you could ever have.